# Cant query object by object id

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my cloud code, I'm trying to query an object from Parse.com right after after I save by using the object id. For some reason its not working right and all the other variations of the starred out line I've tried wont work either.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("NewMessage", function(leanBody, leanSenderName, leanSenderId, request) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("NewMessage");
    query.get(request.object.id, { *************************************************
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("The first object was retrieved");
            leanBody = (results.get("MessageBody"));
            leanSenderName = (results.get("senderName"));
            leanSenderId = (results.get("senderId"));
            getUsers(leanBody, leanSenderName, leanSenderId);
            results.destroy({
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log("deleted");
                }, error: function(results, error){
                }
            });
        }, error: function(error){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Details please. Not working right how? Are you getting any error messages? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ACL set up for the messages? You  may need to use the masterKey.

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```